# How can I install Apache Ant on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, ant

I tried to install Apache Ant on my Mac and I followed the next steps :

1. I downloaded `apache-ant-1.8.1-bin.tar.gz` into my Downloads folder.
2. I moved the file to `/usr/local/` using this commands : `sudo sh` and `mv apache-ant-1.8.1-bin.tar.gz /usr/local/`

Now I want to use `cd /usr/local/` but it's not working, I get back "No such file or directory".

Then I used `cd /usr/` and `ls` commands and it seems that the local folder is there. If I try to access it I get the same error.

Since I already used `sudo su` why I can't access it? Any ideas?

Comment: Can you try all of this again, then when it stops working type history

Copy paste the commands into the question and we can see where its going wrong. I think you just aren't moving the file into the directory.

Comment: What is wrong with the version of ant that Mac OS X already has? Install Xcode and you get ant, maven, all the Java development and lots of other useful stuff for development.

Comment: Can you run "ls -ld /usr/local"?  It sounds like you've made a file called "/usr/local".  :)

Comment: (Mac user) ant --version does not display any version, however, I can see that ant is part of the Android Studio's install of gradle.  I do not see any ant on my system related to Xcode.  What is the recommendation to either enable using ant in gradle or installing yet-another copy using homebrew.

Answer (score 398, accepted):

Ant is already installed on some older versions of Mac OS X, so you should run `ant -version` to test if it is installed before attempting to install it.

If it is not already installed, then your best bet is to install [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) (`brew install ant`) or [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) (`sudo port install apache-ant`), and use those tools to install Apache Ant.

Alternatively, though I would highly advise using Homebrew or MacPorts instead, you can install Apache Ant manually. To do so, you would need to:

1. Decompress the .tar.gz file.
2. Optionally put it somewhere.
3. Put the "bin" subdirectory in your path.

The commands that you would need, assuming `apache-ant-1.8.1-bin.tar.gz` (replace 1.8.1 with the actual version) were still in your Downloads directory, would be the following (explanatory comments included):

```
cd ~/Downloads # Let's get into your downloads folder.
tar -xvzf apache-ant-1.8.1-bin.tar.gz # Extract the folder
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local # Ensure that /usr/local exists
sudo cp -rf apache-ant-1.8.1-bin /usr/local/apache-ant # Copy it into /usr/local
# Add the new version of Ant to current terminal session
export PATH=/usr/local/apache-ant/bin:"$PATH"
# Add the new version of Ant to future terminal sessions
echo 'export PATH=/usr/local/apache-ant/bin:"$PATH"' >> ~/.profile
# Verify new version of ant
ant -version
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I didn't know that ant is already installed on my system.

I already have Xcode installed, and I needed Ant to setup the environment for GTW and Android development.

Thank you.

Comment: For the record, there seem to be systems that don't have ant installed; this could have changed since you answered this.  I'm running 10.9 and it doesn't have ant anywhere

Comment: same here...10.9 doesn't have ant installed by default

Comment: Just a heads up: the last line should be `ant -version`, with one hyphen

Comment: On newer versions of OS X, looks like ".profile" should instead be ".bash_profile"

Comment: Its still not on 10.14  So I needed to install. I just installed using brew that was simple and easy.

Comment: HomeBrew still opens /usr/local/bin for any random root-kit that happens to look at your computer. It is a security hole you can drive a tanker through.

Answer (score 183):

For MacOS Maveriks (10.9 and perhaps later versions too), Apache Ant does not come bundled with the operating system and so must be installed manually. You can use brew to easily install ant. Simply execute the following command in a terminal window to install brew:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

It's a medium sized download which took me 10min to download and install. Just follow the process which involves installing various components. If you already have brew installed, make sure it's up to date by executing:

```
brew update
```

Once installed you can simply type:

```
brew install ant
```

Ant is now installed and available through the "ant" command in the terminal.

To test the installation, just type "`ant -version`" into a terminal window. You should get the following output:

> Apache Ant(TM) version X.X.X compiled on MONTH DAY YEAR

Source: [Error executing command 'ant' on Mac OS X 10.9 Mavericks when building for Android with PhoneGap/Cordova](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19495610/error-executing-command-ant-on-mac-os-x-10-9-mavericks-when-building-for-andro)

If you are getting errors installing Brew, try uninstalling first using the command:

```
rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar /usr/local/.git && brew cleanup
```

Thanks to OrangeDog and other users for providing additional information.

Comment: had an error with permissions on `/usr/local` so need to run `sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local`

Comment: That worked but the homebrew installation is a bit weird because although /usr/local/bin/ant is a symbolic link to ../Cellar/ant/1.9.6/bin/ant if you need any customs jars they need to go into ../Cellar/ant/1.9.6/libexec/lib not  ../Cellar/ant/1.9.6/lib, and also if you set ANT_HOME to /usr/local/Cellar/ant/1.9.6 it breaks ant so you have to leave it unset

Comment: After trying many other things I switched to this answer and it works :). Thank you. Only thing I need to do is, to delete the old version of xCode (ie. 7.3.1 where in current version is 9.0, not sure about what the dependency is but after deleting xCode 7.3.1, everything works like a charm.)

Answer (score 45):

If you have MacPorts installed (https://www.macports.org/), do this:

```
sudo port install apache-ant
```

Comment: Yep, since Java was removed in 10.9 this seems like the way to go.

Answer (score 40):

If you're a homebrew user instead of macports, homebrew has an ant recipe.

`brew install ant`

Answer (score 6):

To get Ant running on your Mac in 5 minutes, follow these steps.

Open up your terminal.

Perform these commands in order:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

`brew install ant`

If you don't have Java installed yet, you will get the following error: "Error: An unsatisfied requirement failed this build."
Run this command next:  `brew cask install java` to fix this.

The installation will resume.

Check your version of by running this command:

`ant -version`

And you're ready to go!

Answer (score 1):

Use Brew is always good way to install ANT and other needs.
To install type below command on terminal.

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

after Brew installation , type

```
brew install ant
```

This will install Ant on your system. Also you will not need to worry about setting up the path.

Also i have documented on the same - [How to Install ANT on Mac OS?](http://iphoneexample.blogspot.com/2018/04/install-ant-mac-os.html)

Answer (score 0):

The only way i could get my ant version updated on the mac from 1.8.2 to 1.9.1 was by following instructions here

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Ant/User_Guide

Answer (score 0):

MacPorts will install ant for you in MacOSX 10.9.  Just use

```
$ sudo port install apache-ant
```

and it will install.

Comment: How is this different from the already existing answer by Karl von Moor??