# Error executing command 'ant' on Mac OS X 10.9 Mavericks when building for Android with PhoneGap/Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, ant, osx-mavericks

Today I tried PhoneGap/Cordova with **Mac OS X Mavericks**. Building for iOS went just fine, but building for Android wasn't without some guesswork.

I installed Android 4.2.2 via the Android SDK Manager (I had to use the older **API v17** since it wasn't compatible with a newer one), added the **`PATH environment variables`** for the SDK's `platform-tools` and `tools` and thought I was ready to take off by running the command:

```
phonegap run android
```

Nevertheless, I got the following error:

```
[phonegap] detecting Android SDK environment...
[phonegap] using the local environment
[phonegap] adding the Android platform...
[error] An error occured during creation of android sub-project. ERROR : executing command 'ant', make sure you have ant installed and added to your path.
```

Comment: Same happening for me... Installing it via brew solved it!

Comment: i went to the /bin Folder, and still I had the same command not found Problem, installing it with brew helped, I still dont understand why it wasnt working before, if I run ant -v from the bin Folder I dont Need to set Environment varibales, this is so strange...

Answer (score 361, accepted):

The error message proved to be true as Apache Ant isn't in the path of Mac OS X Mavericks anymore.

Bulletproof solution:

1. Download and install Homebrew by executing following command in terminal:

   > ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
2. Install Apache Ant via Homebrew by executing

   > brew install ant

Run the PhoneGap build again and it should successfully compile and install your Android app.

Comment: Ant is in homebrew-core now. Simply use `brew install ant`

Comment: how can i install 'ant' for windows and set the path of it

Comment: @MuhammadHusnain: I suppose you should ask a separate question on Stack Overflow for this one

Comment: COMMAND UPDATE:  ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go/install)"

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/610157/how-do-i-install-ant-on-os-x-mavericks for updated `brew` instructions.

Comment: Don't forget to execute "brew doctor" after installing brew and before using brew to install ant.

Comment: i tried ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)" it say unable to access 'https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/': Could not resolve proxy:"****" Failed during: git fetch origin master:refs/remotes/origin/master -n how to fix this

Comment: i tried ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go/install) it returns ">" and do nothing please help me with the issue

Comment: @CharanGiri: it seems that you're connecting to the internet via a proxy server. If so, please try to re-execute that command using a direct internet connection instead

Comment: @Mobiletainment Yes that is the issue proxy made installation process go bad.

Comment: @Mobiletainment I'm getting an error when I do brew install ant: curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
Error: Download failed: http://www.gtlib.gatech.edu/pub/apache/ant/binaries/apache-ant-1.9.2-bin.tar.gz

It looks like the file doesn't exist?  Do I have to update brew maybe?

Comment: Works like charm .. i just need to do .. brew update and then brew install ant  -- ADT was already been installed on my Mac.

Comment: Don't forget `brew update` before you use it, if you already have homebrew installed....

Comment: This also fixed the problem on Yosemite

Answer (score 45):

You can install ANT through macports or homebrew.

But if you want to do without 3rd party package managers, the problem can simply be fixed by downloading the [binary release](http://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi) from the apache ANT web site and adding the binary to your system PATH.

---

For example, on Mountain Lion, in `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.bashrc` my path was setup like this:

```
export ANT_HOME="/usr/share/ant"
export PATH=$PATH:$ANT_HOME/bin
```

So after uncompressing `apache-ant-1.9.2-bin.tar.bz2` I moved the resulting directory to `/usr/share/` and renamed it `ant`.

Simple as that, the issue is fixed.

---

**Note** Don't forget to `sudo chown -R root:wheel /usr/share/ant`

Comment: I did something very similar since I don't use homebrew or macports and on mine, I also did not have anything in my path for it.  I downloaded the binary release, unzipped it and created a folder called ant in /usr/local then copied from the unzipped binary the bin and lib folder to /usr/local/ant, after that add /usr/local/ant/bin to your path and restart terminal and all was golden, just do what Coyote said and you will have phonegap CLI working in no time.

Comment: **This should be the accepted answer.** Lean and clean. Install what you need. Using **Apache Ant** only takes 2 minutes of installing.

Answer (score 28):

As an alternative to homebrew, you could download and install [macports](http://www.macports.org). Once you have macports, you can use:

`sudo port install apache-ant`

Comment: @Goaler444: Are you using an old version of macports? Try `port search ant` and look for Apache Ant there.

Comment: Yep, that was it, updated ports by entering 'sudo port -v selfupdate' and it worked. Thanks :)

Comment: @JohnMark i still get same error please help. i followed the process you mentioned do i need to install any other

Comment: Is `ant` on your PATH? If you type `which ant` in the terminal do you get anything?

Comment: @JohnMark thank you for response when i typed which ant i got "/usr/local/bin/ant"

Answer (score 21):

it don't needed port and brew!
because you have android sdk package.

.1 edit your .bash_profile

```
export ANT_HOME="[your android_sdk_path/eclipse/plugins/org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609]" 

// its only my org.apache.ant version, check your org.apache.ant version

export PATH=$PATH:$ANT_HOME/bin
```

.2 make ant command that can executed

```
chmod 770 [your ANT_HOME/bin/ant]
```

.3 test if you see below message. that's success!

command line execute: ant

Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!

Build failed

Comment: My Eclipse is installed in another location. After setting `ANT_HOME="/Applications/eclipse/plugins/orig.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609"` it worked!

Answer (score 14):

I encountered the same issue when trying to use Cordova. Turns out I already had brew, try `which brew`, but it was outdated. So, I had to update it first:

1. Update brew: `brew update`
2. Install Apache Ant: `brew install ant`

Answer (score 7):

In my case, I have macport installed already. I simply updated my macport:

```
sudo port selfupdate

sudo port upgrade outdated
```

Then install apache-ant:

```
sudo port install apache-ant
```

Finally, I add ant to my alias list in my `.bash_profile`:

```
alias ant='/opt/local/bin/ant'
```

Then you are all set.

Answer (score 3):

For OSX your path needs to include `/Users/yourusername`

their example:  `/Development/adt-bundle/sdk/platform-tools` 
needs to be:    `/Users/yourusername/Development/adt-bundle/sdk/platform-tools`