# How to add platform android (cordova) on Mac

Tags: android, macos, cordova, osx-mavericks, ionic-framework

i have follow the instructions.[phonegab docs](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html) and [How to add android to cordova platform? PATH error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975421/how-to-add-android-to-cordova-platform-path-error) 
[image: export PATH]

my .bash_profile:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
export PATH=$PATH:~/Development/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140321/sdk/platform-tools
export PATH=${PATH}:~/Development/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140321/sdk/platform-tools:~/Development/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140321/sdk/tools
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

but still Error while i executing cordova platform add android or ionic platform android:

```
Error: The command "android" failed. Make sure you have the latest Android SDK installed, and the "android" command (inside the tools/ folder) is added to your path.
```

Any Solutions? thank you

Comment: can u edit your post with .bash_profile text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to run `android` in command line. if the command is not found, it's mean that the path of android sdk that registered is still wrong

Answer (score 1):

AndroidDev PATH

export PATH=${PATH}:~/android-sdk-linux/tools

export PATH=${PATH}:~/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools

You have to manually reload your setting like for Ubuntu I am using this command "$ source ~/.bashrc"

Comment: yes, i using this command source ~/.bash_profile
but still error

Answer (score 0):

Thank you All for your clue of solutions. I try add `$HOME` because `/Development` directory in `/Home` directory and i followed code `RVM` in my .bash_profile:

```
`[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
eval "$(rbenv init -)"`
```

The solutions in [How to add android to cordova platform? PATH error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975421/how-to-add-android-to-cordova-platform-path-error) i followed symbol `~` for initialize `/Development` directory in `/Home` directory, but it's not working. and I try follow code `RVM` in my .bash_profile use `$HOME`.

this is my .bash_profile:

```
 export PATH=${PATH}:$HOME/Development/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140321/sdk/platform-tools:$HOME/Development/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140321/sdk/tools
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

and then run command `source ~/.bash_profile`. Solved