# Getting error when adding Android to Phonegap project

Tags: android, cordova

I am new in phonegap. I am getting error when I add android in phonegap. I have used [this steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19495610/error-executing-command-ant-on-mac-os-x-10-9-mavericks-when-building-for-andro) to solve this error but I am still getting this error:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126 
throw e; 
^ 
Error: An error occured during creation of android sub-project. 

/Users/ss/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:126 
throw e; 
^ 
Error: The command "android" failed. Make sure you have the latest Android SDK installed, and the "android" command (inside the tools/ folder) is added to your path. 
at /Users/ss/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/lib/check_reqs.js:85:29 
at _rejected (/Users/ss/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:808:24) 
at /Users/ss/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:834:30 
at Promise.when (/Users/ss/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:1079:31) 
at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/Users/sss/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:752:41) 
at /Users/ss/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:574:44 
at flush (/Users/ss/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17) 
at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13) 

at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/platform.js:244:30 
at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:641:7)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is step-by-step instructions on the PhoneGap Doc'.you can use this to solve the issue [link](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.8.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android)

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `/pathToAndroidFolder/sdk/platform-tools` and `/pathToAndroidFolder/sdk/tools` to your $PATH

steps for Mac OSX: edit your .bash_profile using nano or any other editor

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

add this line

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/Users/ss/Documents/Software/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130729/sdk/tools:/Users/ss/Documents/Software/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130729/sdk/platform-tools
```

open a new terminal window to make it work, or use this command to make it work on the curren terminal window:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: in which SO do you develop? do you know what is the $PATH variable?

Comment: hello2 ss$ PATH /Users/ss/Documents/Software/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130729/sdk/platform-tools 
-bash: PATH: command not found i am doning like this

Comment: in which SO do you develop?

Comment: MacBook Pro , i am using

Comment: I've added the steps for Mac OSX

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45100/discussion-between-sport-and-jcesar)

Comment: I have this and still the same error. 

export HOME="/Users/rover"
export ANDROID_SDK="$HOME/Documents/Dev/Android/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk"
export ANDROID_HOME="$ANDROID_SDK/tools"
export ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS="$ANDROID_SDK/platform-tools"
export PATH="$ANDROID_HOME:$ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS:$ANDROID_SDK/build-tools:$PATH"
export ANT_HOME="/usr/local/bin/ant"
#export PATH="$PATH:$ANT_HOME/bin"


  $ which ant
/usr/local/bin/ant
  $ ls /usr/local/bin/ant
/usr/local/bin/ant

$ ant -v
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.4

$ cordova --version
4.0.0

error is: node_modules/q/q.js:126 throw e;

Answer (score 0):

For OSX your path needs to include /Users/yourusername

their example: /Development/adt-bundle/sdk/platform-tools
needs to be: /Users/yourusername/Development/adt-bundle/sdk/platform-tools

check your path with echo $PATH (use caps, it's case sensitive!)