# Apache Ant 1.9.6 Installation on Mac OSx - Does not run - Command not Found

Tags: macos, bash, ant

I downloaded and installed apache ant 1.9.6 on my Mac OSx El Capitan 10.11.3 in /usr/local/, added the path to the bash_profile, however, I am unable to make it run. I get the following message back, as opposed to the version

```
-bash: ant: command not found
```

I did a lot of stackoverflow, however, couldn't find solution to this.

This is how my /usr/local looks:
[image]

This is how my bash_profile parameters for apache ant looks:

```
# Apache Ant
export ANT_HOME=“/usr/local/ant”
export PATH=$PATH:$ANT_HOME/bin
```

Could you please give me any hint that you may have.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The detailed and easy steps of installing ant using homebrew on Mac OSX is already discussed here:

[How can I install Apache Ant on Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222804/how-can-i-install-apache-ant-on-mac-os-x/20984975#20984975)

I installed homebrew and I was able to successfully install ant using homebrew package.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the quotes when you set `ANT_HOME`
It should be

```
export ANT_HOME=/usr/local/ant
```

This is only tangentially related to your issue, but you may want to look into [homebrew](http://brew.sh/), using this package manager on my mac I simply do
`brew intall ant` It gets your PATH setup automatically.
It also lets you upgrade to future versions with `brew upgrade ant`

Comment: Thanks @thekbb Homebrew helped me to install ant successfully.